# How to arrange columns based on a particular order of values present in the rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-order-by

Example:
Table Structure:

```
EMP_ID    SAL_MONTHWISE(JAN)   SAL_MONTHWISE(FEB) SAL_MONTHWISE(MAR)
1              10000                15000              8000
2              20000                2000               10000
3              50000                60000              40000
```

New Format Required: In the Increasing order of the salary for each employee

```
EMP_ID    SAL_MONTH1         SAL_MONTH2        SAL_MONTH3
1            8000               10000             15000
2           2000                10000             20000
3            40000              50000             60000
```

Thanks In Advance!!

Comment: new format means, whether you are inserting from main table to another table??

Comment: I want the new format from a select statement

Comment: Use `LEAST` and `GREATEST` functions.

Comment: @ Lalit Kumar B  can you just explain how to do it in a select query?

Comment: you shoud go with plsql for the above.

Comment: @Exhausted, SQL has the ability to do a lot of complex things. Do  not jump to PL/SQL when it could be done in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more generic solution which would work with more than three columns is to unpivot the columns into separate rows, work out what order the values should be in, and pivot them back into columns. From 11g you can unpivot with

```
select * from your_table
unpivot (sal for month in (sal_jan as 'Jan', sal_feb as 'Feb', sal_mar as 'Mar'));
```

which gives you:

```
    EMP_ID MONTH        SAL
---------- ----- ----------
         1 Jan        10000 
         1 Feb        15000 
         1 Mar         8000 
         2 Jan        20000 
         2 Feb         2000 
         2 Mar        10000 
         3 Jan        50000 
         3 Feb        60000 
         3 Mar        40000
```

You don't really care about the month name. Then add a row number pseudocolumn order by the salary value:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by sal) as rn
from your_table
unpivot (sal for month in (sal_jan as 'Jan', sal_feb as 'Feb', sal_mar as 'Mar')) t;
```

And then pivot that back:

```
select * from (
  select t.emp_id, t.sal,
    row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by sal) as rn
  from your_table
  unpivot (sal for month in (sal_jan as 'Jan', sal_feb as 'Feb', sal_mar as 'Mar')) t
)
pivot (max(sal) as sal for (rn) in (1 as "1", 2 as "2", 3 as "3"))
order by emp_id;

    EMP_ID      1_SAL      2_SAL      3_SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1       8000      10000      15000 
         2       2000      10000      20000 
         3      40000      50000      60000
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/177d0/1). This is fairly easy to extend for more columns, just by adding value pairs to the `in` clauses of the pivot and unpivot sections.

If you're using an earlier version - which isn't clear as you tagged the question with both 11g and 10g - you have to manually unpivot and pivot which is a bit more long-winded; to unpivot:

```
with unpivot_data as (
  select level as unpivot_rn from dual connect by level <= 3
)
select t.emp_id,
  case ud.unpivot_rn
    when 1 then t.sal_jan
    when 2 then t.sal_feb
    when 3 then t.sal_mar
  end as sal
from t42 t
cross join unpivot_data ud;
```

... where the number of rows in the `connect by` and the number of case `when` clauses are the number of columns you have; then add the row number based on the salary:

```
with unpivot_data as (
  select level as unpivot_rn from dual connect by level <= 3
),
tmp_data as (
  select t.emp_id,
    case ud.unpivot_rn
      when 1 then t.sal_jan
      when 2 then t.sal_feb
      when 3 then t.sal_mar
    end as sal
  from t42 t
  cross join unpivot_data ud
)
select td.emp_id, td.sal,
  row_number() over (partition by td.emp_id order by td.sal) as rn
from tmp_data td;
```

And then pivot the old-fashioned way using `max(case ...)` and `group by`:

```
with unpivot_data as (
  select level as unpivot_rn from dual connect by level <= 3
),
tmp_data as (
  select t.emp_id,
    case ud.unpivot_rn
      when 1 then t.sal_jan
      when 2 then t.sal_feb
      when 3 then t.sal_mar
    end as sal
  from your_table t
  cross join unpivot_data ud
),
tmp_with_rn as (
  select td.emp_id, td.sal,
    row_number() over (partition by td.emp_id order by td.sal) as rn
  from tmp_data td
)
select twr.emp_id,
  max(case when twr.rn = 1 then twr.sal end) as month_1,
  max(case when twr.rn = 2 then twr.sal end) as month_2,
  max(case when twr.rn = 3 then twr.sal end) as month_3
from tmp_with_rn twr
group by twr.emp_id
order by emp_id;

    EMP_ID    MONTH_1    MONTH_2    MONTH_3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1       8000      10000      15000 
         2       2000      10000      20000 
         3      40000      50000      60000
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/177d0/3). There are now three places you need to change if the number of columns increases, but it's still fairly simple to do.

Comment: It is going to kill the performance. Yes, it is generic, however, to code explicitly for 12 months isn't that big problem.

Answer (score 2):

For the first and last column in your desired output, it is easy to do with **LEAST** and **GREATEST** functions. For the rest other columns, I would go with a **CASE** construct.

**EDIT** The CASE should have the WHEN conditions as AND and not OR.

```
SQL> WITH data AS
  2    ( SELECT 1 emp_id, 10000 jan, 15000 feb, 8000 mar FROM dual
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 2 , 20000 , 2000 , 10000 FROM dual
  5    UNION ALL
  6    SELECT 3 , 50000 , 60000 , 40000 FROM dual
  7    )
  8  SELECT emp_id,
  9    least(jan, feb, mar) jan,
 10    CASE
 11      WHEN jan > least(jan, feb, mar)
 12      AND jan   < greatest(jan, feb, mar)
 13      THEN jan
 14      WHEN feb > least(jan, feb, mar)
 15      AND feb   < greatest(jan, feb, mar)
 16      THEN feb
 17      WHEN mar > least(jan, feb, mar)
 18      AND mar   < greatest(jan, feb, mar)
 19      THEN mar
 20    END feb,
 21    greatest(jan, feb, mar) mar
 22  FROM DATA
 23  /

    EMP_ID        JAN        FEB        MAR
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1       8000      10000      15000
         2       2000      10000      20000
         3      40000      50000      60000

SQL>
```

Comment: this will give only first and last, still other values cannot be handled here.

Comment: @Exhausted, Don't say *cannot* . See the updated answer.

Comment: @LalitKumarB i doesn't mean actual cannot, but when you handle like this, the code will become messy when there is *n* columns. unless generic script is there to handle all such thing.

Comment: The mantra is, never do in PL/SQL if you could do the same in plain SQL :-)